# Conditional role inclusion fails in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-role

I want to run an Ansible role conditionally, i.e. only when some binary does NOT exist (which for me implies absence of some particular app installation).

Something like the pattern used [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9374).

Using the following code in my playbook:

```
  - hosts: my_host

    tasks:
      - name: check app existence
        command: /opt/my_app/somebinary
        register: myapp_exists
        ignore_errors: yes

    roles:
      - { role: myconditional_role, when: myapp_exists|failed }
      - another_role_to_be_included_either_way
```

Here is the output:

```
PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [my_host ]

TASK [ myconditional_role : create temporary installation directory] ***********************
fatal: [my_host]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! The conditional check 'myapp_exists|failed' failed. The error was: ERROR! |failed expects a dictionary"}
```

Why is the conditional check failing?

Using `ansible 2.0.0.2` on `Ubuntu 16.04.01`

btw: "create temporary installation directory" is the name of the first main task of the conditionally included role.

Answer (score 2):

Tasks are executed **after** roles, so `myapp_exists` is undefined.
Use `pre_tasks` instead.

Also keep in mind that `when` is not actually a conditional role, it just attaches this `when` statement to every task in your role.

Comment: so any suggested pattern for conditional role inclusion for the specific use case?

Comment: I'd move the test inside role's main.yml tasks file and include install.yml if needed.